# Focus an Out of Focus window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a winforms with multiple windows.I show the window by using

myform.show();

Currently the form's top bar (with the close and minimize button) is out of focus. I need it to be focused.

I tried

myform.Focus();

It does not work.

For Example this how the window looks now..

[image]

I need it to be like this

[image]

I need it to be focused (see the top bar) without user intervention of clicking on it.Please advice.

Comment: .Focus() should work. Maybe you do something with your host form after focusing myform that forces host form to intercept focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some other control is taking focus away from the form after you are calling myform.Focus();

To get around this, you can wait until the form (and hopefully most of your controls) have been loaded and shown on the form, and then call this.Focus();

In the Form.Shown() event handler call this.Focus();

For Example:

```
    private void Form_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Focus();
    }
```